# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero unity

Tags: c#, android, json, unity-game-engine, assets

I need help with this one. It says that on my logcat :

> System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

Here's what so far I did.

> 1.) `string full_path = string.Format("{0} {1}",Application.streamingAssetsPath + path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);`
>
> 2.) `string full_path = string.Format("{0}/{1}",Application.streamingAssetsPath + path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);`
>
> 3.) `string full_path = string.Format("{0}",Application.streamingAssetsPath + path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);`

All of'em doesn't work. I Still got the error on my logcat

Here's my actual code:

```
// Load 2 (StreamingAssets).
public static string LoadJsonFromStreamingAssets(string path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder)
{
    string json = null;
    try
    {
        //Android Platform
    #if UNITY_ANDROID

        string full_path = string.Format("{0}/{1}",Application.streamingAssetsPath + path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);

        // Android only use WWW to read file
        WWW reader = new WWW(full_path);
        while (!reader.isDone){}

        json = reader.text;

        // PK Debug 2017.12.11
        Debug.Log("STEP 1. ");
        Debug.Log(json);

        JsonData itemData = JsonMapper.ToObject(json);

        Debug.Log("STEP 2. ");

     #else
        string full_path = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Application.streamingAssetsPath, path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(full_path);
        json = reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        reader.Close();
     #endif
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogWarningFormat("Failed to Load.\n{0}\n{1}", e, path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);
    }
    return json;
}
```

Comment: 3) above shouldn't give that error, but why do you need to use `string.Format( )` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, by changing:

```
string full_path = string.Format("{0}/{1}",Application.streamingAssetsPath + path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);
```

to this:

```
string full_path = string.Format("{0}/{1}",Application.streamingAssetsPath, path_with_extention_under_streaming_assets_folder);
```

Comment: Well...yes. You asked for two arguments (`{0}` and `{1}`) and then tried to pass only one argument ("a"+"b" is one--concatenated--string). So of course the solution is to pass *two actual arguments.*

Comment: @Draco18s yeah . That was so idiot of me . hahaha I'm sorry